# getting my javascript prompt to repeat itself, regardless of input

Tags: javascript, syntax, prompt

I have been trying to teach myself javascript, and  have been trying to make my own version of a "hangman game" to help master the logic and commands of js.  I can not get the prompt i am using to repeat itself, and am having trouble figuring out what it is that makes a prompt repeat.

This is my code:

```js
var secretWords = ["batman", "Donkey kong", "ninja", "programming"];
var chosenWord = secretWords[Math.floor(Math.random() * secretWords.length)];
var guesses = 8;
console.log(chosenWord);
var letters = chosenWord.length;
const guess = prompt("GUESS A LETTER");
var guessLowerCase = guess.toLowerCase();
var isGuessedLetterInWord = chosenWord.includes(guessLowerCase);
var gameOver = guesses = 0

for (const i of guess) {
  if (isGuessedLetterInWord) {
    alert('nice');
  } else {
    alert('wrong');
  }
}
```

Comment: Hint: a `while` loop may help you here :)

Comment: I think you'll want to move the prompt inside the loop. Then after each input do your checks. Right now it'll only ever prompt the user once.

Comment: When you prompt, leave the loop if nothing entered  - you run a good risk of never stopping the loop otherwise

Comment: also  `gameOver = guesses === 0` but only if you do `guesses--`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hangman implementation. It might help you develop your own.

`findLetter` constructs a regular expression and then does a case-insensitive and global match of a guess against a word. Each letter might match more than one position in the chosen word.

A `while` loop runs the game for as long as the answer has not been guessed and there are still "misses" remaining.

If a guessed-letter matches nothing in the chosen word, then `missCount` is incremented and the loop continues.

Correctly-guessed letters are recorded in their correct position, in an array called `hits`. If the letters in that array form the chosen word before your misses run out, you win; otherwise you lose.

```js
const findLetter = (ltr, seq) => [...seq.matchAll(new RegExp(ltr || null,'ig'))]
const randomFrom = (arr) => arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]    
const strings = {
    guess: (remaining, hits, clue) => `${countdown[remaining]}  ${clue}:  ${hits}  Guess a letter.`,
    wrong: `Wrong...`,
    match: `Nice! You found a match.`,
    guessed: (seq) => `Well done! You correctly guessed "${seq}".`,
    failed: (seq) => `Game Over. You ran out of guesses. The word or phrase was "${seq}".`,
    half: `You have only half of your guesses remaining!`,
    last: `Last guess!`,
}
const countdown = [strings.last, "2.", strings.half, "4.", "5.", "6."]

function game({ seqs, maxMissCount = 6 }) {
    const { seq, clue } = randomFrom(seqs)
    const hits = [...seq.replace(/\w/gi, '_')]
    let guessed = false
    let missCount = 0

    while(!guessed && (missCount < maxMissCount)) {
        const response = prompt(strings.guess(maxMissCount-missCount-1, hits.join(' '), clue))
        if(response === null) break
        const [letter] = response
        const matches = findLetter(letter, seq)
        if (!matches.length) { alert(strings.wrong); ++missCount; continue }
        matches.forEach(({ 0: firstLetter, index }) => hits[index] = firstLetter)
        alert(strings.match)
        guessed = (hits.join('') === seq)
    }

    if (guessed) alert(strings.guessed(seq))
    else alert(strings.failed(seq))
}

const seqs = [{ seq: 'To be or not to be. That is the question', clue: 'Shakespearean phrase' }, 
              { seq: 'A drop in the ocean', clue: 'A small amount' },
              { seq: 'Break a leg', clue: `Thespians' retort` },
              { seq: 'Far from the madding crowd', clue: 'Peace and quiet' },
              { seq: 'Truth is stranger than fiction', clue: 'Funny old world' }]
game({ seqs })
```